# Azure application gateway returns http status code 499

Tags: azure, nginx, azure-application-gateway

I have some api deployed to azure webapp. In front of this app there is a Application gateway.

When I access the app through .azurewebsites.net url it works fine, but when I try to hit the same path through a custom domain of the app gw - it fails.

In application gateway logs in `AzureDiagnostics` part of it I see it fails with 499 error.

Application gateway has a number of multi-site listeners configured, is of `Standard V2` tier (and therefore does not have any WAF applied) and manually scaled to 2 instances.

What is rejecting those calls? How can I overcome this issue?

Comment: Are you running a Linux / windows stack in azure?

Comment: Do not think that we have any real control over Application Gateway backbones

Comment: As per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/http-status-codes code 499 means that the client closed the connection before it received a response. So in other words it's not the server rejecting the calls - it's the client aborting the call.